# PHPStorm ${TYPE_HINT} adding erroneous slash

Tags: phpstorm, phpdoc

I'm using PHPStorm 8.0.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. 
When PHPStorm auto-completes function docs, it is erroneously adding a slash "\" before the class name of parameters as shown below:

```
/**
 * @param \Exception $exceptionToLog
 * @param \Varien_Object $objectBeingActedUpon
 * @return array
 */
```

The class names should be Exception and Varien_Object, not \Exception and \Varien_Object. Has anyone else experienced this issue? I've looked in Settings | Code Style | PHP and didn't find anything there that would imply an erroneously hard-coded slash. Didn't see anything obvious in Settings | File and Code Templates  either

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Just solved this myself, I had clicked the "Use fully-qualified class names" checkbox in Settings | Code Style | PHP, which apparently prefixes the classes with the namespace